# Android Studio doesn't work with Genymotion

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I'm trying to open a simple app on Genymotion and I got this error

```
Unexpected error: package manager reports that package com.codeherenow.trafficlights has not been installed: Expected string 'Package [com.codeherenow.trafficlights]' not found in output: Can't find service: package

java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:113)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.InstalledApks.setInstalled(InstalledApks.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.uploadAndInstallApk(AndroidRunningState.java:1205)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.doPrepareAndStart(AndroidRunningState.java:920)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.prepareAndStartApp(AndroidRunningState.java:874)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.prepareAndStartAppWhenDeviceIsOnline(AndroidRunningState.java:842)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.doStart(AndroidRunningState.java:676)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.start(AndroidRunningState.java:652)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState$1.run(AndroidRunningState.java:298)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
```

And in the event log:

```
01:50:05 PM Gradle build finished in 3 sec
01:50:39 PM Session 'app': running
01:50:41 PM Throwable
            Unexpected error: package manager reports that package com.codeherenow.trafficlights has not been installed: Expected string 'Package [com.codeherenow.trafficlights]' not found in output: Can't find service: package
```

When I try to run the app on my phone, it works without problems.

Any idea?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79778

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I opened Virtual Box -> My Device -> Preferences -> Network and changed **Host-only Network** to **Bridge**